# Alterar dados Mysql no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Tenho a Tb_trabalhadores onde é preenchida atraves de um formulario.
E depois criei outra pagina para poder alterar esses dados.

Alterar.php

```
$id = $exibe["id"];

$Nome = $exibe["Nome"];

$Morada = $exibe["Morada"];

$Tipo = $exibe["Tipo"];

$Email = $exibe["Email"];
$AlvaraNumero = $exibe["AlvaraNumero"];

$AlvaraValidade = $exibe["AlvaraValidade"];

$AlvaraAnexo = $exibe["AlvaraAnexo"];

$AcidenteNumero = $exibe["AcidenteNumero"];

$AcidenteValidade = $exibe["AcidenteValidade"];

 $AcidenteAnexo = $exibe["AcidenteAnexo"];

 $SeguroNumero = $exibe["SeguroNumero"];

$SeguroValidade = $exibe["SeguroValidade"];

 $SeguroAnexo = $exibe["SeguroAnexo"];

$FinancasValidade = $exibe["FinancasValidade"];

 $FinancasAnexo = $exibe["FinancasAnexo"];

 $SocialValidade = $exibe["SocialValidade"];

$SocialAnexo = $exibe["SocialAnexo"];

$RemuneracaoValidade = $exibe["RemuneracaoValidade"];

$RemuneracaoAnexo = $exibe["RemuneracaoAnexo"];

$InstaladorNumero = $exibe["InstaladorNumero"];

$InstaladorValidade = $exibe["InstaladorValidade"];

$InstaladorAnexo = $exibe["InstaladorAnexo"];

 $MontadorNumero = $exibe["MontadorNumero"];

$MontadorValidade = $exibe["MontadorValidade"];

$MontadorAnexo = $exibe["MontadorAnexo"];
}

?>

 <form action="salvaralteracao.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    Nome<input type="Varchar" name="Nome" value="<?php echo $Nome; ?>"><p>
    Morada<input type="Text" name="Morada" value="<?php echo $Morada; ?>"><p>
    Email<input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>"><p>
            AlvaraNumero<input type="integer" name="AlvaraNumero" value="<?php echo $AlvaraNumero; ?>"><p>
    AlvaraValidade<input type="date" name="AlvaraValidade" value="<?php echo $AlvaraValidade; ?>"><p>
    AlvaraAnexo<input type="file" name="AlvaraAnexo" value="<?php echo $AlvaraAnexo; ?>"><p>
    AcidenteNumero<input type="integer" name="AcidenteNumero" value="<?php echo $AcidenteNumero; ?>"><p>
    AcidenteValidade<input type="Date" name="AcidenteValidade" value="<?php echo $AcidenteValidade; ?>"><p>
    AcidenteAnexo<input type="file" name="AcidenteAnexo" value="<?php echo $AcidenteAnexo; ?>"><p>
    SeguroNumero<input type="integer" name="SeguroNumero" value="<?php echo $SeguroNumero; ?>"><p>
    SeguroValidade<input type="Date" name="SeguroValidade" value="<?php echo $SeguroValidade; ?>"><p>
    SeguroAnexo<input type="file" name="SeguroAnexo" value="<?php echo $SeguroAnexo; ?>"><p>
    FinancasValidade<input type="Date" name="FinancasValidade" value="<?php echo $FinancasValidade; ?>"><p>
    FinancasAnexo<input type="file" name="FinancasAnexo" value="<?php echo $FinancasAnexo; ?>"><p>
    SocialValidade<input type="Date" name="SocialValidade" value="<?php echo $SocialValidade; ?>"><p>
    SocialAnexo<input type="file" name="SocialAnexo" value="<?php echo $SocialAnexo; ?>"><p>
    RemuneracaoValidade<input type="Date" name="RemuneracaoValidade" value="<?php echo $RemuneracaoValidade; ?>"><p>
    RemuneracaoAnexo<input type="file" name="RemuneracaoAnexo" value="<?php echo $RemuneracaoAnexo; ?>"><p>
    InstaladorNumero<input type="integer" name="InstaladorNumero" value="<?php echo $InstaladorNumero; ?>"><p>
    InstaladorValidade<input type="Date" name="InstaladorValidade" value="<?php echo $InstaladorValidade; ?>"><p>
    InstaladorAnexo<input type="file" name="InstaladorAnexo" value="<?php echo $InstaladorAnexo; ?>"><p>
    MontadorNumero<input type="integer" name="MontadorNumero" value="<?php echo $MontadorNumero; ?>"><p>
    MontadorValidade<input type="Date" name="MontadorValidade" value="<?php echo $MontadorValidade; ?>"><p>
    MontadorAnexo<input type="file" name="MontadorAnexo" value="<?php echo $MontadorAnexo; ?>"><p>      
 <input type="submit" value="Guardar">

 </form>
```

salvaralteracao.php

```
<?php

include("conectar.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];

$Nome = $_POST['Nome'];

$Morada = $_POST['Morada'];

$Email = $_POST['Email'];

    $AlvaraNumero = $_POST["AlvaraNumero"];

$AlvaraValidade = $_POST["AlvaraValidade"];

$AlvaraAnexo = $_POST["AlvaraAnexo"];

$AcidenteNumero = $_POST["AcidenteNumero"];

$AcidenteValidade = $_POST["AcidenteValidade"];

$AcidenteAnexo = $_POST["AcidenteAnexo"];

$SeguroNumero = $_POST["SeguroNumero"];

$SeguroValidade = $_POST["SeguroValidade"];

$SeguroAnexo = $_POST["SeguroAnexo"];

$FinancasValidade = $_POST["FinancasValidade"];

$FinancasAnexo = $_POST["FinancasAnexo"];

$SocialValidade = $_POST["SocialValidade"];

$SocialAnexo = $_POST["SocialAnexo"];

$RemuneracaoValidade = $_POST["RemuneracaoValidade"];

$RemuneracaoAnexo = $_POST["RemuneracaoAnexo"];

$InstaladorNumero = $_POST["InstaladorNumero"];

$InstaladorValidade = $_POST["InstaladorValidade"];

$InstaladorAnexo = $_POST["InstaladorAnexo"];

$MontadorNumero = $_POST["MontadorNumero"];

$MontadorValidade = $_POST["MontadorValidade"];

$MontadorAnexo = $_POST["MontadorAnexo"];


  $sqlinsert = "Update tb_trabalhador SET Nome='$Nome' ,Morada='$Morada',Email='$Email' AlvaraNumero='$AlvaraNumero',AlvaraValidade='$AlvaraValidade',AlvaraAnexo='$AlvaraAnexo',AcidenteNumero='$AcidenteNumero',cidenteValidade='$AcidenteValidade',AcidenteAnexo='$AcidenteAnexo',SeguroNumero='$SeguroNumero',SeguroValidade='$SeguroValidade',SeguroAnexo='$SeguroAnexo',FinancasValidade='$FinancasValidade',FinancasAnexo='$FinancasAnexo',SocialValidade='$SocialValidade',SocialAnexo='$SocialAnexo',RemuneracaoValidade='$RemuneracaoValidade',RemuneracaoAnexo='$RemuneracaoAnexo',InstaladorNumero='$InstaladorNumero',InstaladorValidade='$InstaladorValidade',InstaladorAnexo='$InstaladorAnexo',MontadorNumero='$MontadorNumero',MontadorValidade='$MontadorValidade',MontadorAnexo='$MontadorAnexo' where id=$id ";
  mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
     mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());

  ?>
  <br>
  <a href="administrador.php">
```

Estou com um problema em depois voltar a guardar na tabela.
Será que na parte do Update depois tenho de colocar todos os outros dados da Tabela?

Já esta a funcionar. 
Mas tenho um problema nos ficheiros file. Pois tenho sempre de alterar o seu conteudo pois aparece em branco. 
Por exemplo:

```
AlvaraValidade<input type="date" name="AlvaraValidade" value="<?php echo $AlvaraValidade; ?>"><p>
AlvaraAnexo<input type="file" name="AlvaraAnexo" value="<?php echo $AlvaraAnexo; ?>"><p>
```

Nesse exemplo o primeiro aparece a data antiga e no File não aparece. E depois tenho de voltar a inserir um Anexo.

Comment: Se bem eu percebi, não consegue guardar os dados, certo?

o update à base de dados está correcto?
Experimente: UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET Nome='$Nome', Morada = '$morada', Email = '$Email' WHERE id = '$id'";

Comment: eu tenho assim agora e não dá.
Uma duvida. 
A minha tabela é: Id,Nome,Morada,Tipo,Email,campo,campo2...

Na parte do Update tenho de colocar todos os campos da tabela?

Comment: não, apenas podes colocar os campos a que queres fazer update

Comment: Agora coloquei num comentario os campos todos onde se pode fazer alteração.

Comment: A questão está extremamente confusa assim como as suas "respostas" que não são respostas abaixo?

Comment: No form tenho os dados para alterar. E no campo $AlvaraAnexo = $exibe["AlvaraAnexo"]; não me mostra e so me deixa colocar um novo file

Comment: Detalhe que a função ```mysql_query``` não mais é recomendada para acesso ao banco de dados, devido as várias brechas que resultam em SQL Injections, dentre outros problemas. Prefira uso de [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php) ou [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) no lugar.

Comment: Lembre-se de escolher a melhor resposta. Você faz diversas perguntas e quem responde gosta de ter um feedback também. Abraço.

Answer (score 8):

Altera a sql de

```
 $sqlinsert = "Update tb_trabalhador
                         id,
                         Nome='$Nome',
                         Morada='$Morada',
                         Email='$Email'
                where id='$id' ";
```

para:

```
 $sqlinsert = "Update tb_trabalhador SET
                         Nome='$Nome' ,
                         Morada='$Morada',
                         Email='$Email' 
               where id='$id' ";
```

para que faltou o **set** e remova o id já que ele não será atualizado.

Envie o `id` por `input hidden`

```
<form action="salvaralteracao.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?> " />
```

Lembre que apenas um registro deve ser alterado, nese caso sua consulta precisa de um `WHERE`

```
include("conectar.php");
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'],  FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$sql = mysql_query("Select* From tb_trabalhador WHERE id = $id");

while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   $id = $exibe["id"];
   $Nome = $exibe["Nome"];
   $Morada = $exibe["Morada"];
   $Email = $exibe["Email"];
}
```

Comment: : Undefined variable: id 
E eu tenho la a variavel. Ate alterei o POST
 if ( isset( $_POST['id'] ) )
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}

Comment: No seu form não existe nenhum campo chamado `id` apenas `nome`, `morada` e `email`

Comment: Mas só estou a colocar agora o Id a seguir ao Where e dá-me o mesmo problema.

Comment: Coloco o Id no form? 
Mas nos outros peço para alterar os dados

Comment: @user3253195, sim você precisa de um campo `id` no form, na sql o `id` não será atualizado.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AlvaraNumero='23423432',AlvaraValidade='2014-02-28',AlvaraAnexo='telm__ext.html'' at line 1

Agora tenho isso. tem a haver com a colocação das plicas?

Comment: Pode postar o código que gerou esse erro?

Comment: SQL injection fodido em `$id=$_GET['id'];` e `mysql_query("Select* From tb_trabalhador WHERE id = $id");`. Correu uma lágrima aqui

Comment: Boas, continuou com um problema que é:
Aparece tudo bem para alterar mas quando faço guardar ele não me substitui o que tinha. Acrescenta um novo igual ao outro mas alterado

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que eu entendi você está querendo reformular esse formulário de atualização para que funcione. Segue abaixo uma maneira de fazer.

Neste exemplo é usado apenas um arquivo **Alterar.php**, onde ele identifica se a requisição é uma solicitação de edição ou se é a solicitação do formulário para a edição.

Alterar.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alterar</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// Inclui arquivo de conexão
include("conectar.php");

// Se for uma requisição POST, faz a ação de salvar as informações
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
    $Morada = $_POST['Morada'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];

    $sqlinsert = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET Nome='{$Nome}', Morada='{$Morada}', Email='{$Email}' WHERE id='{$id}' ";
    mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>

    <br/>
    <a href="administrador.php"> Área Administrador </a>

    <?php
} 
else // Se não for uma requisição POST, mostra o formulário
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador WHERE id = {$id}");

    // Verifica se recebeu ao menos um resultado (o que se espera)
    if($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        // Se recebeu, faz a leitura dos dados
        $id = $exibe["id"];
        $Nome = $exibe["Nome"];
        $Morada = $exibe["Morada"];
        $Email = $exibe["Email"];

        // Imprime formulário pré carregado
        ?>
        <form action="Alterar.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            Nome<input type="text" name="Nome" value="<?php echo $Nome; ?>">
            Morada<input type="text" name="Morada" value="<?php echo $Morada; ?>">
            Email <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    else // ID inválido
    {
        // Imprime alerta em javascript e faz o redirecionamento para alguma página
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("ID Inválido!");
            window.location = 'administrador.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse script funcionaria? **SIM**!

Porém ainda pode ser melhorado, pois ele está extremamente vulneráveis a [injeções de scripts](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Algumas dicas para melhorar:

- Valide os dados no cliente com javascript ou jQuery antes da submissão de formulários;
- Valide os dados ao recebe-los no servidor PHP antes de fazer qualquer coisa;
- Tente fazer sua conexão com o banco de dados com [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

Existem muitas outras coisas que podem ser melhoradas, mas, um passo de cada vez.

Comment: Bem galera, como a resposta do nosso colega foi respondida pelo Thiago. Vim deixar uma dica para ele. Seu script está vulnerável a SQL Injection. Procure sobre o assunto é uma medida de segurança importantíssima no desenvolvimento de uma aplicação. Existem funções no PHP que tratam essa falha, como por exemplo o mysql_real_escape_string. Ex: **$nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nome"]);**

Comment: Ao final da resposta eu chego a citar sobre essa vulnerabilidade também. O ideal é não utilizar nenhuma função mysql_..., pois todas já foram depreciadas. Como um bom estudo para o nosso colega user3253195 (risos) fica a dica de se atualizar e usar uma camada de persistência orientada a objeto e nativa (PDO), com todos tratamentos necessários para evitar essas vulnerabilidades (como prepared statement / parameterized statement).

Comment: Desculpe, não vi até essa informação.

Comment: O mais importante aqui é contribuir para o aprendizado e mesmo se tratando de uma função depreciada, sem dúvida serve como complemento. Acredito que a maioria aqui já usou bastante o mysql_, mysqli_, até parar no PDO para aplicações que necessitem de performance ou utilizando algum ORM (Doctrine por exemplo) para ganhar velocidade no desenvolvimento e facilidade no mapeamento. Abraço Hiago!